# Pip for IronPython missing VS2017

Tags: c#, python, visual-studio, pip, ironpython

so I've successfully installed IronPython for VS2017. But basically, I need to be able to call an external python script that has its own imports so I need pip to retrieve these dependencies. I've been to Tools -> Python -> Python Environments. Within here there's a drop-down called Packages, which has a link "Download and install pip package manager". I've clicked this and it has successfully installed pip however, this link should disappear and I should be able to search for packages which isn't the case. [IronPython env not showing pip](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pNW6s.png). [Shared Python env displaying pip](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kLl62.png). Am I missing an extra step or something?